# Applescript to click checkbox in cell in row in outline

Tags: macos, applescript

I have a checkbox in the following hierarchy:
Outline->Row->Cell->Checkbox
This is how it looks in accessibility inspector:

[image: This is how it looks in accessibility inspector]

I need to click on it.

So, I tried:

> `click checkbox 1 of cell 1 of row 3 of outline 1 of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1 of window 1`

This gives the error: 
`Expected end of line, etc. but found number.`

If I try to select the row like this:

> `select row 3 of outline 1 of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1 of window 1`

The row is getting selected.

Also, I can read the properties of the row like so:

> `get properties row 3 of outline 1 of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1 of window 1`

but not the properties of the checkbox/cell using:

> `get properties of checkbox 1 of cell 1 of row 3 of outline 1 of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1 of window 1`

I'm an absolute n00b at applescript, I have no, I idea what is going wrong.

Can anyone help?

PS: I am trying to turn off the screenshot shortcuts with in system preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's choking on the specifier for AXCell. Cell doesn't work. Just use UI Element 1:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click checkbox 1 of UI element 1 of row 3 of outline 1 of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks a Ton! Your fix is working.. But any idea why cell doesn't work? Just asking for future reference.

Comment: For years I've never seen a class name that works for AXCell. Using UI Element is helpful, because you can "get every UI Element of row 1", etc., to examine things. It will find all items, buttons, text boxes, etc.